# R Shiny on Shiny server - how to access the app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have Shiny Server installed and I can use the sample apps (i.e. http://serverip:3838/hello/).

But when I visit http://serverip:3838/myapp/ to use myapp, it's not working (loading till it stops).

Am I missing something in the code or in the way this should be done?

-- (running locally `app.R` from RStudio, works fine)

Info about the app:

- Location: /srv/shiny-server/myapp
- Filename: app.r
- File structure:

  **-- load libraries**

  library(shiny)

  ...

  **-- Connection and queries**

  ```
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                   user = '#',
                   password = '#',
                   host = '#',
                   dbname='#')

  tickets<-dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from table")
  issues_speed_unique<-unique(na.omit(dbGetQuery(con,"Select * from table2")))
  dbDisconnect (con) 

  some aggregations....
  ```

  **-- Server code**

  ```
  shinyServer(
    function(input,output){
       ...
  ```

  **-- ui code**

  ```
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
       ...

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine in RStudio indicates that it is not something related to your program logic. It seems that your folder/file permission may be preventing Shiny Server from accessing your files. I have encountered similar issues before.

Please make sure that user `shiny` (if you used default installation options) have access to your folder and files. I would suggest that you use `chown -R <yourself>:shiny <my-shiny-folder>` and `chmod -R g+s <my-shiny-folder>` so that all files saved to this folder can be accessed by Shiny.

Comment: the folder with my app was owned by my user, while the sample apps are owned by root. So I changed my app's folder to root too. But the browser is still saying: `The connection was reset`. I see that (R)MySQL is pretty unpredictable: sometimes queries very fast, other times is very slow. Is there a way to run the app from the terminal to have the data frames created and  to avoid `The connection was reset` from browser)? If data frames would be created, I should be able to load the app in the browser without problems.

Comment: My set up is: `drwxrws---. 1 root <group> 134 May 20  2016 <shiny-app>` where `<group>` is a group where myself and the system user `shiny` are both members and it works well.